# SDK to handle bluetooth hear rate sensors with errors management

Tags: android, ios, heartrate

we are creating a game for android and iOS, where we want to modify the story based on relaxation/stress levels.
We are thinking about using heart rate sensors like the Polar chest sensors and similar.

I was wondering if any knows about a repo to include in our app to handle the Bluetooth part of the sensors, we don't have experience with accessing to hardware, we implemented some connections and readings but connection is unstable, sometimes it connects, another's connection is lost, sensor is not found....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the developer's page of https://www.rookmotion.com/api, it is an app already made for heart rate monitoring but also has an SDK for third-party developers